# Why do these quotes show up when I print the file?

Tags: python

I create a file using this code:

```
file = open("full_names.txt", "wb")

file.write("Bob Smith\nMichael Jackson\nTony Tiger\nWinston Churchill\nHenry Kissinger\nHamid Karzai\nJohn Major\nJohnny Quest")

file.close()
```

I then run the script to print the file to screen:

```
with open("full_names.txt", "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        first, last = line.strip().split(" ")
        print "Last Name: %r First Name: %r" % (last, first)
```

But the output shows up with quotes around the names, like this:

```
Last Name: 'Smith' First Name: 'Bob'
```

Does any one know why or how to get rid of them?

Comment: You could greatly simplify this example to `print 'Name: %r' % 'Bob'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you replace `%r` with `%s` it should get rid of it.

`%r` shows the representation of the object which should reprsent a value that can be copied and pasted in the python shell to reproduce the object.  `%s` will show the value of the object cast to a string.

As described in the docs
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

---

and `repr` because the concept is pretty cool:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr

Comment: So the 'value of the object cast to a string' is the stuff inside the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Simply because you're using `%r`. Change to `%s` and it will go away =)

```
print "Last Name: %s First Name: %" % (last, first)
```

`%r` is equivalent to `repr(var)` and `%s` is `str(var)`